# Spring aop didn't work

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I try to apply Spring aop in my Spring web project but it didn't work

I put org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.0.4.RELEASE in lib folder of Tomcat 7;

I have the following AspectJ files

```
<!-- AspectJ -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Under META_INF I have  context.xml and aop.xml files

context.xml

```
<Context path="/SpringMVCJPA">
    <Loader
        loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"
        useSystemClassLoaderAsParent="false" />
</Context>
```

and aop.xml

```
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
        <include within="com.example.spring.*" />
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <aspect
            name="org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect" />
        <aspect
            name="org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect" />
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

in root-context.xml file

```
<!-- Enable AspectJ Load Time Weaving -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<context:load-time-weaver/>
```

this is my advice class

```
@Component
@Configurable
@Aspect
public class DummyAdvice {
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DummyAdvice.class);

    @Before("execution(* com.example.spring.ContactServiceImp.findAllByPage(..))")
    public void simpleBeforeAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        logger.info("simpleBeforeAdvice is excuted before : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    }
}
```

But when findAllByPage() is called nothing happens.  Did I do any thing wrong ?

Thanks for spending time on this question.

Comment: Are you sure to use Component, Configurable and Aspect on one class? They should be mutually exclusive...

Answer (score 0):

Question: is the class you are pointcutting a spring bean? I mean, it should marked with one of the following annotations: @component, @service, @repository,...?

Comment: Yes It marked @Service("contactService")
@Repository